# Are transporters used as the main travelling method between cities on 24th century Star Trek Universe Earth?

Tags: star-trek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Common is Same-Planet Transporter Use?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18661/how-common-is-same-planet-transporter-use)

Are transporters used to travel in between Earth cities or are there still conventional (shuttles) or new ways of travelling? I remember vaguely that Commander Riker once said he used all his transporter "rations" on Earth.

Comment: Why would anyone need to commute? Do you think that in Star Trek la-la land that Bob needs to be in to the office by 9 so he can start filing the virtual TPS reports?

Comment: @JohnO Dunno about the TPS reports, but yes, there were a couple episodes that showed working conditions on Earth - including working hours and being in the office.  Both the ones I have in mind were from VOY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Going by [this page](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transporter_credit) and a [Voyager episode](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Non_Sequitur_%28episode%29) where Tom and Harry catch a train to work, I'd say transporter use is very restricted, either to Starfleet personnel and/or sufficiently influential people (mainly politicians), and/or hard to earn (Starfleet may be an exception).

Even in the 24th century, we see that transporters should only be operated by highly-trained personnel (things can still go wrong), not something you'd want in every major city.
This assumes that non-Starfleet people would even want to use them knowing they were going to be "dis-assembled".

Comment: +1 for the episode _Non Sequitur_ from Voyager; that's one of the two I was thinking of in my earlier comment, but didn't have time to look for